# Как портировать .net winforms на mac os?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, macos, .net-core

Всем привет. Возникла задача портировать одно моё приложение написанное на языке c#  (на платформе .Net framework 4.5) на Mac OS.

Так сложилось, что я никогда дела не имел с Mac OS и у меня нет девайса с Mac OS.

Пришел к следующему алгоритму действий:
1. Перевести приложение на .net core 3 (как это сделать я уже представляю)
2. Скомпилировать для Mac OS (как это сделать я не понимаю, если учитывать то что у меня нет девайса с mac os)

**Вопрос 1:**

Правильный и самый простой ли путь я выбрал?

**Вопрос 2:**

Возможно ли как-то скомпилировать проект .Net Core 3 на операционной системе windows для Mac OS??? Если это возможно, то что скачать, где взять? Или обязательно нужно иметь MAC OS чтобы скомпилировать такой проект?

Comment: WinForms Вы при всём желании не "портируете" под macOS. Они windows-only

Comment: @Kir_Antipov очень жаль( 

если на wpf переписать то можно портировать на macOS?

Comment: @XXX нельзя. Если только не воспользоваться эксперементальным фреймворком https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia

Comment: Простого способа нет. Посмотрите в сторону [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/porting-winforms-applications/) у них есть кроссплатформенная реализация winforms, но, скорее всего, придется повозиться с совместимостью.